# Solving the recurrence $T(n) = 128 \, T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right) + n^{13/3} \, \ln n + \ln^4 n$

Tags: recurrence-relations, data-structure

I'm trying to solve the recurrence relation but I keep getting stuck
$$T(n) = 128 \, T\left(\frac{n}{8}\right) + n^{13/3} \, \ln n + \ln^4 n$$
I tried doing this $ m = \ln n$ but couldn't get far.

edit :

I was interested in the asymptotic theta of the equation.

using the master theorem I got :
$ a= 128 b = 8 , log_8(128) = 3/7 $
if I look at the dominant part of f(n) it's of course $n^\frac73$
so by the second case of master theorem
$T(n)= \theta(n\frac73logn)$

sorry for my non existing latex skills :/

Comment: Did you write a code?

Comment: Does $n^2*n^(7/3)$ mean $n^{13/3}$? And does $T(n/8)$ mean $T(\lfloor n/8\rfloor)$?

Comment: @BobDobbs - no i did not

Comment: @AnneBauval - we drop the ceilling or floor values , does not mean floor value

Comment: So the domain of $T$ is not supposed to be $\mathbb N$ but $\mathbb R_+$? If so, you might edit to make this explicit, since the notation $n$ is misleading.

Comment: Or (after reading the accepted answer) should we have guessed that the domain of $T$ is $\{8^p\mid p\in\mathbb N\}$?

Comment: @AnneBauval actually in this particular question the value of n^(log(a) base b) is equivalent to the theta of f(n), therefore T(n) = $\theta$ f(n)
based on the master theorem, no need to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T(n)=128\,T(\tfrac n8)+f(n)$$

Basically you want to transform this into $W(p)-W(p-1)=g(p)$ to be able to calculate $W(p)$ as a telescopic sum:

$$W(p)=W(0)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^p g(i)$$

For that we need $2$ things:

- get rid of the factor $128$

We can set $U(n)=\dfrac{T(n)}{n^a}\implies n^aU(n)=128\dfrac{n^a U(\frac n8)}{8^a}+f(n)$

Therefore we have to get $8^a=128\iff a=\frac 73$

- transform $n\to p$

We can do that by setting $n=8^p$ and $U(n)=W(p)$ since $U(\frac n8)=W(p-1)$.

With $g(p)=\dfrac{f(n)}{n^{\frac 73}}=\dfrac{f(2^{3p})}{2^{7p}}$

In the end it is not complicated as you'll get various $p^\alpha 2^{\beta p}$ to sum up (which is geometric series, or derivative of geometric series), but **very tedious**...

*Note: if you are interested only in the asymptotic, just calculate the dominant term of $\sum g(i)$.*

---

I have calculated the exact value with CAS using the method presented, here it is:

$\displaystyle\begin{align}T(n)&=\tfrac{64}{63}n^{\tfrac{13}{3}}\ln(n)
-\tfrac{64\ln(2)}{1323}n^{\tfrac{13}{3}}
+\Big(\tfrac{64\ln(2)}{1323}+\tfrac{23626442880\ln(2)^4}{33038369407}\Big)n^{\tfrac 73}\\\\
&-\tfrac 1{127}\ln(n)^4
-\tfrac{1536\ln(2)}{16129}\ln(n)^3
-\tfrac{891648\ln(2)^2}{2048383}\ln(n)^2
-\tfrac{233584128\ln(2)^3}{260144641}\ln(n)\\\\
&-\tfrac{23626442880\ln(2)^4}{33038369407}
\end{align}$

Arranged by decreasing dominant terms.

Asymptotically $T(n)\sim \dfrac{64}{63}n^{\tfrac{13}{3}}\ln(n)$

Comment: edit: added solve by CAS.